# convert array of strings to object keys in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have next array

```
const arrayData = ['a', 'b'] as const;
```

this array have next type ArrayType = ('a' | 'b')[];

I want obtain object what coincide with next type:

```
type Type = {
  a: boolean,
  b: boolean,
}
```

expected object

```
   const result : Type = {
     a: false,
     b: false,
   }
```

I want transform `arrayData` to `result`

```
const result: Type = arrayData.reduce((r, key) => {
  return {
    ...r,
    key: false,
  }
}, {});
```

but this code not have valid types

Comment: why use reduce when you can just directly do `const result: Type = {a: false, b: false}`?

Comment: in my code arrayData can have > 20 elements, I want create result from arrayData so as not to duplicate the code,   in my code for result type I use  type R =  { [key in typeof arrayData[number]]: boolean }, but here I simplify it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your first assumptions is wrong:

```js
const foo = ['a', 'b'] as const; // Type is ['a', 'b'], a tuple of literals
const bar = ['a', 'b'];          // Type is ('a' | 'b')[], a list of a union of literals
```

Using the `['a', 'b']` regardless of the `const` you can type it like this:

```js
type ObjectFromList<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>, V = string> = {
  [K in (T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? U : never)]: V
};
```

[Full example on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AMQE4HsC2AZASwGdgAeAFSggA9gIA7AEyKgCUIBDRregGxACCGDBxCkSGAvQDmAPgA0UAGpQAvFAlS5aqAG8AUFCgBtANJQpUABSUadJi3Zce-ISLFSAZhAxQAqrJQAPz+UABcUPQQAG4+AJQAuhFK+gC+ANz6+sg8JFC8xMA6xgDkHCWKJXAlCVAcLDn0JFmgkFDk4NDq8EiomLiEJKStEFie+YWKcFhYvJz0spnZuUWeMxEdbeoGRkYcEcAYAK4Q8oa7cBGeHLxEp+dGyAfH96lAA)

Explaining:

- `T extends ReadonlyArray<string>` require a type parameter that is an array with elements that can become strings, being Readonly allows you to use `const`. Every string literal type can be passed into a string.
- `T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? U : never` is a conditional that means: "if T is an array, get the type of its elements (`U`), otherwise no type".
  We required T to extend an array, so we can set never after `:` meaning we know it will never happen.
  `infer U` will infer the smallest set of types possible for the T, which in your case is the union of the string literals (`'a' | 'b'`)
- `[K in ...]: V` uses all the possible values in the element of the array as keys pointing to values of type `V` (which we set the default to `string`, but you can pass another one).

Lastly, about the reduce. You need to set the type that you are working with during the iterations:

```js
const result: Type = arrayData.reduce((r, key) => {
  return {
    ...r,
    [key]: false,
  }
}, {} as Type); // Here
```

To restrict the type exactly you need to type both the reduce, by typing the initial accumulator, and the return of the function:

```js
const result: Type = arrayData.reduce((r, key): Type /* HERE */ => {
  return {
    ...r,
    [key]: false,
  }
}, {} as Type);
```

[Full example on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AMQE4HsC2AZASwGdgAeAFSggA9gIA7AEyKgCUIBDRregGxACCGDBxCkSGAvQDmAPgA0UAGpQAvFAlS5aqAG8AUFCgBtANJQpUABSUadJi3Zce-ISLFSAZhAxQAqrJQAPz+UABcUPQQAG4+AJQAuhFK+gC+ANz6+sg8JFAcwqIAIhzAHDrGAOQclYqVcJUJ+Sw59CRZoJBQ5ODQ6vBIqJi4hCSknRBYnvmFICVlinBYWLyc9LKZ2bnAUBgQRACuvMARPV3qBe7zHAB0e4wHyBBWVhiKANYQIHGnvVAA9AAqKAACQAoqwwVBAf81IEDEY9sADhh6HpDEYoDdsW8MUZkBFgBgDhB5HiTJ8QEkoJ4OLwiKSMak0opdKlmt1enF0kA)

Comment: your solution permitted const obj: ObjectFromList<typeof bar> = { c: ''  };   but 'c'   not in arrayData,   because I use   `as const`

Comment: @HardCoreQual I changed to support const and added a link to it on the playground :)

Comment: For convert type I use type R = { [key in typeof arrayData[number]]: boolean }, but .reduce use operator `as`  ,  I can add in reduce between ..r and [key]: false ,, another key what not in arrayData (for example c: true), and typescript ignore it

Comment: Oh, okay, that is due to how types work for function parameters. The type is inferred from the function and then checked against the target, not the other way around. And that check allows for extra parameters. If you want just the exact type you need to [add the return type explicitly. I'll edit the answer with an example

Comment: For the typing, I personally prefer to be explicit, but you can do it like this too: `Record<typeof arrayData[number], boolean>`. I find the `[number]` to be quite elusive for those that are glancing at the code.

Comment: I think need not use reduce and use another method,  in last version can in reduce  add this line:   if (key === 'a') return r;   and typescript ignore it, but result not have key 'a'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233680/discussion-between-hardcorequal-and-luiz-ferraz).

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 issues in your sample:

1. the dynamic key for an object should be inside brackets: (`key:` should be `[key]:`
2. you can define the type of initial `reduce` accumulator by `as` operator in TypeScript.

```js
const arrayData = ['a', 'b'] as const;

type Type = {
  a: boolean,
  b: boolean,
}

const result: Type = arrayData.reduce((r, key: string) => {
  return {
    ...r,
    [key]: false,
  }
}, {} as Type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a generic now.

```
type Type = {
  [K in typeof arrayData[number]]: boolean
}
```